# How to reduce the width of the first (left-hand) column of a table?

Tags: tables

I have a table made on excel2latex add-in. The problem is that I have 1 column of variables names and 6 more of results. It's not fitting on page. The column for variable names if too large and I want to adjust the width to make it fit the page. I'd much appreciate your help. My code is the following:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Validation of compensation variables}} &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)} \\
    VARIABLES & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Forecast} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Forecast} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Forecast} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Forecast} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Forecast} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Forecast} \\
    \midrule
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    Lag\_F & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.925***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.872***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.927***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.903***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.928***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1.929***} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0345)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0356)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0347)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0348)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0345)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0345)} \\
    Opts ratio & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.193***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0463)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    OptsVst & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0791*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0454)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    NumOpts & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0617} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0648)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    NumUnexOpts & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.140***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0533)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    Dopts & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0926**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0438)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    DoptsV\_l & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.0998**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0388)} \\
    \#Analysts & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.000302} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.000273} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.000263} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.000260} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.000285} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.000282} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.000189)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.000190)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.000190)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.000189)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.000189)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.000189)} \\
    ROA   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{185.8***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{184.2***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{178.9***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{172.1***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{182.8***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{183.6***} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(43.86)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(47.52)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(44.21)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(44.38)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(44.22)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(44.07)} \\
    Investment & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.711**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.530} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.763**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.743**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.779**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.769**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.352)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.374)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.353)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.360)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.353)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.353)} \\
    Market-to-book & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.637**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3.222***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.594**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.590**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.639**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.636**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.081)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.178)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.085)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.125)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.081)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.078)} \\
    Liquidity & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.643**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.987**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.494*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.630**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.517**} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-1.533**} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.763)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.854)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.768)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.770)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.768)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.766)} \\
    EPS volat & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0877***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0851***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0868***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0889***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0867***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.0867***} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0152)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0160)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0152)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0153)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0152)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0152)} \\
    Ret volat & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19.22***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19.63***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19.38***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19.65***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19.18***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-19.17***} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.605)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.677)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.612)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.624)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.608)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.609)} \\
    Leverage & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.341***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.368***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.358***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.365***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.349***} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.350***} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0797)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0834)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0801)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0808)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0799)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0797)} \\
    Constant & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.200} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.377} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.217} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.350} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.204} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.196} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.253)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.232)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.261)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.252)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.253)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.252)} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{18,729} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{16,541} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{18,624} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{17,952} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{18,736} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{18,736} \\
    Industry FE & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} \\
    year FE & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YES} \\
    \midrule
    Robust standard errors in parentheses &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    *** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1 &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Please make your code a compilable MWE by adding the used documentclass and relevant packages. In this case it is escpecially important so one can see the actual width of your text. Additionally, you can savely remove all occurences of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{ }` and additionally replace all occurences of constructs like `\multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.000302}` by the contents of the last pair of `{}`, as they are unnecessary. To horizontally center contents in a table column, use `c` instead of `r` for the corresponding column.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- By all means, immediately get rid of all these useless `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` directives. Most of the other `\multicolumn` wrappers aren't needed either.
- Use `\multicolumn{5}{l}{...}` wrappers for the two footer lines.
- Align all numbers on their respective decimal markers by loading the `dcolumn` package and its `D` column type.
- Optional: Ditch the `\centering` directive and use a `tabular*` environment to make the table take up the full width of the textblock automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page size parameters suitably
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}} for alignment on decimal markers
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\sym[1]{^{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\caption{Add caption}  
\label{tab:addlabel}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make tabular* figure out optimal value of this param.
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{6}{d{3.7}} }
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Validation of compensation variables}}  \\
\midrule
Variables & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Forecast} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} \\
\midrule
Lag\_F & 1.925\sym{***} & 1.872\sym{***} & 1.927\sym{***} & 1.903\sym{***} & 1.928\sym{***} & 1.929\sym{***} \\
       & (0.0345) & (0.0356) & (0.0347) & (0.0348) & (0.0345) & (0.0345) \\
Opts ratio & 0.193\sym{***}\\
          & (0.0463)\\
OptsVst &  & -0.0791\sym{*}  \\
          &  & (0.0454)  \\
NumOpts &  &  & 0.0617 &  &  &  \\
          &  &  & (0.0648) &  &  &  \\
NumUnexOpts &  &  &  & -0.140\sym{***} &  &  \\
          &  &  &  & (0.0533) &  &  \\
Dopts &  &  &  &  & 0.0926\sym{**} &  \\
          &  &  &  &  & (0.0438) &  \\
DoptsV\_l& 0.0998\sym{**} \\
         & (0.0388) \\
\#Analysts & -0.000302 & -0.000273 & -0.000263 & -0.000260 & -0.000285 & -0.000282 \\
          & (0.000189) & (0.000190) & (0.000190) & (0.000189) & (0.000189) & (0.000189) \\
ROA   & 185.8\sym{***} & 184.2\sym{***} & 178.9\sym{***} & 172.1\sym{***} & 182.8\sym{***} & 183.6\sym{***} \\
          & (43.86) & (47.52) & (44.21) & (44.38) & (44.22) & (44.07) \\
Investment & -0.711\sym{**} & -0.530 & -0.763\sym{**} & -0.743\sym{**} & -0.779\sym{**} & -0.769\sym{**} \\
          & (0.352) & (0.374) & (0.353) & (0.360) & (0.353) & (0.353) \\
Market-to-book & 2.637\sym{**} & 3.222\sym{***} & 2.594\sym{**} & 2.590\sym{**} & 2.639\sym{**} & 2.636\sym{**} \\
          & (1.081) & (1.178) & (1.085) & (1.125) & (1.081) & (1.078) \\
Liquidity & -1.643\sym{**} & -1.987\sym{**} & -1.494\sym{*} & -1.630\sym{**} & -1.517\sym{**} & -1.533\sym{**} \\
          & (0.763) & (0.854) & (0.768) & (0.770) & (0.768) & (0.766) \\
EPS volat & -0.0877\sym{***} & -0.0851\sym{***} & -0.0868\sym{***} & -0.0889\sym{***} & -0.0867\sym{***} & -0.0867\sym{***} \\
          & (0.0152) & (0.0160) & (0.0152) & (0.0153) & (0.0152) & (0.0152) \\
Ret volat & -19.22\sym{***} & -19.63\sym{***} & -19.38\sym{***} & -19.65\sym{***} & -19.18\sym{***} & -19.17\sym{***} \\
          & (1.605) & (1.677) & (1.612) & (1.624) & (1.608) & (1.609) \\
Leverage & 0.341\sym{***} & 0.368\sym{***} & 0.358\sym{***} & 0.365\sym{***} & 0.349\sym{***} & 0.350\sym{***} \\
          & (0.0797) & (0.0834) & (0.0801) & (0.0808) & (0.0799) & (0.0797) \\
Constant & 0.200 & 0.377 & 0.217 & 0.350 & 0.204 & 0.196 \\
          & (0.253) & (0.232) & (0.261) & (0.252) & (0.253) & (0.252) \\
\addlinespace
Observations & \mc{18,729} & \mc{16,541} & \mc{18,624} & \mc{17,952} & \mc{18,736} & \mc{18,736} \\
Industry FE & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} \\
Year FE & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} & \mc{YES} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{$\sym{***}\ p<0.01$; $\sym{**}\ p<0.05$; $\sym{*}\ p<0.1$}  \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `excel2latex` utility is known to make for ugly tables, adding useless `\multicolumn` commands everywhere.

In the following I reduced some data to the format 1.4 in order to save space. With `\footnotesize` and a small decrease to `\tabcolsep` the table fits in the margin of `article`; your mileage may vary, so first try at natural size, then `\small` or `\footnotesize`, adjusting the value in `\addtolength` by looking at the final overfull measure and dividing it by 12.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]

\centering
\caption{Validation of compensation variables}
\label{tab:addlabel}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NM}{m}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\sisetup{
  input-open-uncertainty  = ,
  input-close-uncertainty = ,
  table-align-text-pre    = false,
  table-align-text-post   = false,
  table-space-text-pre    = (,
  table-space-text-post   = ),
  table-format=-1.4,
}

\footnotesize
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2.3pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{S} }
\toprule
Variables & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Forecast} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}
          & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} \\
    \midrule
    Lag\_F & 1.925\NM{***} & 1.872\NM{***} & 1.927\NM{***} & 1.903\NM{***} & 1.928\NM{***} & 1.929\NM{***} \\
          & (0.0345) & (0.0356) & (0.0347) & (0.0348) & (0.0345) & (0.0345) \\
\addlinespace
    Opts ratio & 0.193\NM{***} &  &  &  &  &  \\
          & (0.0463) &  &  &  &  &  \\
\addlinespace
    OptsVst &  & -0.0791\NM{*} &  &  &  &  \\
          &  & (0.0454) &  &  &  &  \\
\addlinespace
    NumOpts &  &  & 0.0617 &  &  &  \\
          &  &  & (0.0648) &  &  &  \\
\addlinespace
    NumUnexOpts &  &  &  & -0.140\NM{***} &  &  \\
          &  &  &  & (0.0533) &  &  \\
\addlinespace
    Dopts &  &  &  &  & 0.0926\NM{**} &  \\
          &  &  &  &  & (0.0438) &  \\
\addlinespace
    DoptsV\_l &  &  &  &  &  & 0.0998\NM{**} \\
          &  &  &  &  &  & (0.0388) \\
\addlinespace
    \#Analysts (${}\times10^3$) & -0.302 & -0.273 & -0.263 & -0.260 & -0.285 & -0.282 \\
          & (0.189) & (0.190) & (0.190) & (0.189) & (0.189) & (0.189) \\
\addlinespace
    ROA (${}\times10^{-2}$)   & 1.858\NM{***} & 1.842\NM{***} & 1.789\NM{***} & 1.721\NM{***} & 1.828\NM{***} & 1.836\NM{***} \\
          & (0.4386) & (0.4752) & (0.4421) & (0.4438) & (0.4422) & (0.4407) \\
\addlinespace
    Investment & -0.711\NM{**} & -0.530 & -0.763\NM{**} & -0.743\NM{**} & -0.779\NM{**} & -0.769\NM{**} \\
          & (0.352) & (0.374) & (0.353) & (0.360) & (0.353) & (0.353) \\
\addlinespace
    Market-to-book & 2.637\NM{**} & 3.222\NM{***} & 2.594\NM{**} & 2.590\NM{**} & 2.639\NM{**} & 2.636\NM{**} \\
          & (1.081) & (1.178) & (1.085) & (1.125) & (1.081) & (1.078) \\
\addlinespace
    Liquidity & -1.643\NM{**} & -1.987\NM{**} & -1.494\NM{*} & -1.630\NM{**} & -1.517\NM{**} & -1.533\NM{**} \\
          & (0.763) & (0.854) & (0.768) & (0.770) & (0.768) & (0.766) \\
\addlinespace
    EPS volat & -0.0877\NM{***} & -0.0851\NM{***} & -0.0868\NM{***} & -0.0889\NM{***} & -0.0867\NM{***} & -0.0867\NM{***} \\
          & (0.0152) & (0.0160) & (0.0152) & (0.0153) & (0.0152) & (0.0152) \\
\addlinespace
    Ret volat (${}\times10^{-1}$) & -1.922\NM{***} & -1.963\NM{***} & -1.938\NM{***} & -1.965\NM{***} & -1.918\NM{***} & -1.917\NM{***} \\
          & (0.1605) & (0.1677) & (0.1612) & (0.1624) & (0.1608) & (0.1609) \\
\addlinespace
    Leverage & 0.341\NM{***} & 0.368\NM{***} & 0.358\NM{***} & 0.365\NM{***} & 0.349\NM{***} & 0.350\NM{***} \\
          & (0.0797) & (0.0834) & (0.0801) & (0.0808) & (0.0799) & (0.0797) \\
\addlinespace
    Constant & 0.200 & 0.377 & 0.217 & 0.350 & 0.204 & 0.196 \\
          & (0.253) & (0.232) & (0.261) & (0.252) & (0.253) & (0.252) \\
    \midrule
    Observations & \num{18729} & \num{16541} & \num{18624} & \num{17952} & \num{18736} & \num{18736} \\
    Industry FE & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} \\
    year FE & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Robust standard errors in parentheses,
      \textsuperscript{***} $p<0.01$, \textsuperscript{**} $p<0.05$, \textsuperscript{*} $p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A variant with some improvements, using `siunitx` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable, makecell, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering\sisetup{table-format=-2.4, table-number-alignment = center, table-space-text-post = ***, table-align-text-post = false, table-space-text-pre =(, table-align-text-pre = false}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.8pt}
  \small\renewcommand{\cellset}{\normalsize}
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\small}l*{6}{S}}
    \multicolumn{7}{>{\normalsize}l}{\textbf{Validation of compensation variables}} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    VARIABLES & {\makecell{(1) \\Forecast}} & {\makecell{(2)\\Forecast}} & {\makecell{(3)\\Forecast}} & {\makecell{(4)\\Forecast}} & {\makecell{(5)\\Forecast}} & {\makecell{(6)\\Forecast}} \\
    \midrule
    Lag\_F & 1.925*** & 1.872*** & 1.927*** & 1.903*** & 1.928*** & 1.929*** \\
                   & {(0.0345) } & {(0.0356)} & {(0.0347)} & {(0.0348)} & {(0.0345)} & {(0.0345)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Opts ratio & 0.193*** \\
                   & {(0.0463)} \\
    OptsVst & & -0.0791* \\
                   & & {(0.0454)} \\
    NumOpts & & & 0.0617 \\
                   & & & {(0.0648)} \\
    NumUnexOpts & & & & -0.140*** \\
                   & & & & {(0.0533)} \\
    Dopts & & & & & 0.0926** \\
                   & & & & & {(0.0438)} \\
    DoptsV\_l & & & & & & 0.0998** \\
                   & & & & & & {(0.0388)} \\
    \addlinespace
    \#Analysts & -0.000302 & -0.000273 & -0.000263 & -0.000260 & -0.000285 & -0.000282 \\
                   & {(}0.000189{)} & {(}0.000190{)} & {(}0.000190{)} & {(}0.000189{)} & {(}0.000189{)} & {(}0.000189{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    ROA & 185.8*** & 184.2*** & 178.9*** & 172.1*** & 182.8*** & 183.6*** \\
                   & {(}43.86{)} & {(}47.52{)} & {(}44.21{)} & {(}44.38{)} & {(}44.22{)} & {(}44.07{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Investment & -0.711** & -0.530 & -0.763** & -0.743** & -0.779** & -0.769** \\
                   & {(}0.352{)} & {(}0.374{)} & {(}0.353{)} & {(}0.360{)} & {(}0.353{)} & {(}0.353{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Market-to-book & 2.637** & 3.222*** & 2.594** & 2.590** & 2.639** & 2.636** \\
                   & {(}1.081{)} & {(}1.178{)} & {(}1.085{)} & {(}1.125{)} & {(}1.081{)} & {(}1.078{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Liquidity & -1.643** & -1.987** & -1.494* & -1.630** & -1.517** & -1.533** \\
                   & {(}0.763{)} & {(}0.854{)} & {(}0.768{)} & {(}0.770{)} & {(}0.768{)} & {(}0.766{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    EPS volat & -0.0877*** & -0.0851*** & -0.0868*** & -0.0889*** & -0.0867*** & -0.0867*** \\
                   & {(}0.0152{)} & {(}0.0160{)} & {(}0.0152{)} & {(}0.0153{)} & {(}0.0152{)} & {(}0.0152{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Ret volat & -19.22*** & -19.63*** & -19.38*** & -19.65*** & -19.18*** & -19.17*** \\
                   & {(}1.605{)} & {(}1.677{)} & {(}1.612{)} & {(}1.624{)} & {(}1.608{)} & {(}1.609{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Leverage & 0.341*** & 0.368*** & 0.358*** & 0.365*** & 0.349*** & 0.350*** \\
                   & {(}0.0797{)} & {(}0.0834{)} & {(}0.0801{)} & {(}0.0808{)} & {(}0.0799{)} & {(}0.0797{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Constant & 0.200 & 0.377 & 0.217 & 0.350 & 0.204 & 0.196 \\
                   & {(}0.253{)} & {(}0.232{)} & {(}0.261{)} & {(}0.252{)} & {(}0.253{)} & {(}0.252{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Observations & 18,729 & 16,541 & 18,624 & 17,952 & 18,736 & 18,736 \\
    \addlinespace
    Industry FE & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} \\
    year FE & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} & {YES} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{*** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1} \\
  \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It work out fine. Now the table fitts to the page. However, I have some other tables that I'm creating with excel2latex. Is that a way to create more presentable tables, without all this multicolumns?

Comment: Well, it seems excel2latex doesn't do a very good job.  All these multicolumns aren't required. To remove them in a sensible time, I had to automate ‘Search and Replace’  with  `regular expressions`.

Comment: @FelipeDamasceno: If your tables contents is mainly made of numbers, perhaps it would be faster to export to `.csv` format, and use a package like `csvsimple` or `datatools` which can make a LaTeX table out of a .csv file

Comment: Yes, my tables are mainly on this format. To make a latex table out of a csv file is like imput a figure? I just need to write the path to the file?